React With ASP.NET template cannot create package.json
I'm using VS2022 to create an application using React with ASP.NET template. Checked all prerequisites in this link.
After I click the create button it gave me a prompt to input package name and select framework and variant(I chose TypeScript).
prompt during project initialization
After that it generated a project but it cannot run since the Package.json is not created in reactwithasp.client. project structure created
Can anyone please help? Thanks a lot!
I also tried React With ASP.NET TypeScript template but it has same issue. The only difference is that with the TypeScript template the .client folder is empty.
I thought it might be access issue so ran VS2022 with admin but it generated same result.

I had the same issue; updating to the latest version of Node.js worked for me. Also, if you are using NVM to manage Node versions, make sure you're pointing to that last version or at least to a compatible version to use with the .NetCore template.

I updated NODE, NPM and NPX and that seemed to fix my issue.
